# Need to execute some code when nested ng-if in my custom directive ends compilation and recreates element

Tags: html, angularjs

Have simple directive

```
.directive('test', function () {
            return {
                templateUrl: 'dir.html',
                scope: {
                    date: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.find('.date-picker').attr('type', 'email');
                }
            };
        });
```

And simple template for directive

```
<div ng-if="date">
    <h1>Date is true</h1>
    <input class="date date-picker" type="text"/>
</div>
<div ng-if="!date">
    <h1>Date is false</h1>
</div>
```

I want to do smth with child element inside any div with ng-if.

My code https://plnkr.co/edit/ewHfBj6SjCss1cs4CsY7?p=preview

Comment: note that loading order of jquery and angular is important if you want to use jQuery inside angular. Demo is reversed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an watch to the date and then execute the code you want to run when it changes.

```
scope.$watch('date', function(dateValue){
  if(dateValue){
    //Code to run if true
  }else{
    // code to run if false
  }
});
```

Comment: Also with ng-init directive ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit ) you can execute code in any place of your template, but according documentation it is a bad practice.

Comment: @BobSponge I tried it once. But it not suites for my original source. That input that i want to init as datepicker can not initialize as datepicker because its ng-class dir is not compiled to that time.

Comment: @YuriMolchanov Note that if date is a Date() object you cant watch that object. It won't trigger the watch if the time is changed since it is the same object and $watch won't trigger unless the object is changed. Instead watch date.getTime() in that case.

Comment: @Klante, yeah, i know. I made that input as a text container, and i watch as a string change. So watch's triggering. )